# OnEdit & OnChange at Google Sheets script API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Well, i have a simple problem...

I made a inventory management tool, that extracts info from other sheet and blocks the cell so the players can't edit the formula. I already have this onEdit command, but when i edit in the shet ITEM and go to CHAR, the formula update doens't trigger the event.

The players edit a cell on sheets ITEM, and get loaded on the sheet CHAR. And both should trigger the same script, no problem if twice. This is a item grade coloring system.

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
  
  var c = event.value;  // We know we edited cell, just get the value
  var background = 'black'; // Assume 1 <= c <= 2

    if (ss.getName() == "CHAR" || ss.getName() == "ITEM") {

    if (c.endsWith("1*")) {
    background = 'black';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("2*")) {
    background = '#cccccc';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("3*")) {
    background = '#00ff00';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("4*")) {
    background = '#0000ff';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("5*")) {
    background = '#9900ff';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("6*")) {
    background = '#ff00ff';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("7*")) {
    background = '#ebc49d';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("8*")) {
    background = '#ff9900';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("9*")) {
    background = '#ff0000';
    }
    else if (c.endsWith("10*")) {
    background = '#00ffff';
    }

  changedCell.setFontColor(background);
}
```

The extract formula is this per example:

```
=IF(ITEM!B66; ITEM!C66; " ")
```

If a checkbox on item is marked, the item shows a name, or not.

Is there anyway so it can run on the formula update or change?

Comment: changing the sheet is not an edit

Comment: Well, bad explained. When i make an edit on the sheet ITEM, the script works well, but when i go to CHAR, the formula update doens't trigger onEdit. I'm trying to find the "onChange" or "onUpdate", but i'm really stuck on how to use.

Comment: onEdit triggers only fire on user edits.  Not formula or other script edits.  There is no trigger that will fire on formula or other script edits.  There is no work around

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

Like the comments have indicated, `onEdit(event)` cannot trigger on a change of value computed by a formula, since the formula itself has not been edited.

You would need to **explicitly** define the range you want to set background to on `CHAR` sheet. Since your formula is static, or at least blocked from editing in public, there should be only one mapping on which range you need based on `event.range`.